# Printing Equation in Python

Tags: python

I want to print an equation in python which will show up like math mode in latex.
I have written-

```
b = (3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3)
print ((3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3), '=',b)
```

And want it to first print the equation and then the answer, however it prints the answer = the answer.
Is there a way of changing this?

Comment: It would be hard, not feasible, needless to print latex format output in terminal, However you may try replacing `(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3)` with `"(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3)"`

Comment: Use sympy, has pretty printing for terminal, and mathjax for html environments.

Comment: there's a simpleeval module which works well...

Answer (score 5):

You could keep the expression in string and use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to calculate it:

```
>>> b = "(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3)"
>>> print (b, '=',eval(b))
(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3) = 3.239611801277483
```

Comment: I was about to comment something along the lines of "`eval is evil!`" but then I realized the program isn't `eval()`'ing inputs, so this is a really good application for the `eval()` method.

Comment: anyway, if you want to avoid `eval` there's a simple `simpleeval` third party which works really well.

Answer (score 1):

```
print("(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3) = ", b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to the above answers you could also print the question like this.

```
 print("(3**2 + 5**2)**(1/3) = " + str(b))
```